# Tabla dinamica ngFor Angular

Tags: html, angular

Hola buenas me gustaría saber como podría separar los datos que me llegan por filas en una tabla..

En una variable que recorro con un for me llegan 3 valores..y con lo que tengo a continuacion se me muestran todos juntos en un mismo TR , me gustaría mostrarlos en tr independientes cada valor.

```html
       <tr>
                <ng-container *ngIf="valores">
                  <ng-container *ngFor="let t of valores.listadevalores">{{t.valorPrincipal}}</ng-container>
                </ng-container>
            </tr>
```

Comment: Se que ya te dieron la solución, pero tengo una duda. Por que en tu pregunta, en el código usas 'ng-container' ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes que poner el `ngFor` en el la etiqueta `<tr>` y el `ngIf` yo lo pondría en el la etiqueta `<table>`, es decir, si no hay valores no muestra la tabla.

```html
<table *ngIf="valores">
  <tr *ngFor="let t of valores.listadevalores">
    <th>{{ t.valorPrincipal }}</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Espero haberte ayudado